# R merge columns in the same file with identical column names and remove duplicates

Tags: r

I have a dataframe containing columns with identical names for some reason. I wish to combine these columns with the same name with removing the duplicates

I tried using merge but I do not want to enter the column names one by one like merge (x, y)

Also clearly when I use unique I dont get what i want

```
a <- c(1,2,3,4,5)
data <- cbind(a,a)

b <- as.data.frame(lapply(split.default(data, colnames(data)), function(x) Reduce(`unique`, x)))
```

Comment: Hi Seigfried. I'd like to try to help, but I'm not 100% clear on what you are trying to accomplish. In the example you provided, it looks like you could just drop one of the "a" columns. However, I'm sure your problem is more complex than that. Do you think you could add a little more context to your question/example?

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: Sorry if i wasnt specific enough

Comment: a <- c(1,2,3,4,5,7,NA)
b <- c(1,2,3,4,5,NA,6)

data <- cbind(a,b)
colnames(data) <- c("Test","Test")

So I have 2 columns with the same name
Since they have the same name they should be merged into one and without duplication of values

So the output should be
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,NA

Comment: @Seigfried as per your explanation what would be the output of this dataframe? `structure(c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7, NA, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, NA, 6, 1, 2, 
3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7), .Dim = c(7L, 4L), .Dimnames = list(
    NULL, c("Test1", "Test1", "Test2", "Test2")))`

Comment: The output will be 2 columns
Test 1 and Test 2.

Test1 will contain 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,NA
Test2 will contain 1,2,3,4,5,6,7

I do not care about the NAs and would like to remove them

I just want to keep a single instance of everything i.e. removing duplicates

a) first between two columns with the same name i.e. just keep 2 cols Test1 and Test2
b) inside each column among the values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
rm(list = ls())
cat("\014")
dev.off()

dd <- read.table("~/Downloads/test.txt" , header = F, sep = "\t")

names(dd) <- as.matrix(dd[1, ])
dd <- dd[-1, ]

oo <- lapply(unique(colnames(dd)) , function(colName){
  i <- colName
  colNu <- which(colnames(dd) == i)
  dim(dd[,colNu])
  unique(as.character(unlist(dd[,colNu])))

})

names(oo) <- unique(colnames(dd))
```